# How do I compute a double weighted average? In other words, an average with two weighting factors.

Tags: average

This might be a simple question...

I was wondering, how does one take a double weighted average? (honestly, don't know if that is what it is called). For example, let's say that we are working with data from the table below:

```
Cellphone type | # of phones sold | # of hours spent on design | Profit
--------------   ----------------  ---------------------------   ------
Iphone                1,000                    200                $30K
Samsung               3,000                    150                $40K
HTC                   7,000                    140                $35K
```

1) I know that the simple average of the profit is: `$35K`

2) I also know that the average weighed by `# of phones sold` is: `$35.9091K`

3) And, that the average weighted by `# of hours spent on design` is `$34.4898K`

Now, what is the profit average weighted by `# of phones sold` and `# of hours spent on design`? Is it a simple average between 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without further information. The second weighted average should be weighted with respect to how important the metrics are to you - perhaps you care twice as much about # of hours than # of sales. In that case you would do

$$ave= 2[\text{weighted by hours worked}]+1[\text{weighted by sales}]$$

Comment: You make an interesting point. But, I am wondering if the "further information" (the seconded weighted average) can be obtained by a combination of the two weighting factors.

Comment: @Frankie No, there is no guarantee that that is the correct choice of weights.